# Shipping R packages to the nodes in SparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, hadoop2, sparkr

Hi I am wondering if there is a solution to ship R packages with `spark-submit` and use them on the compute nodes in SparkR?

Comment: You'll have to install them using a configuration management system that allows you to define the state of your IT infrastructure, then automatically enforces the correct state, like puppet or chef.

Comment: It is indeed possible, as zip-packaged R packages can be installed through `install.packages("<package name>, repos=NULL)` and the zip files get shipped to YARN cache (which is the working dir or SparkR). I couldn't find a very straightforward method though so hopefully someone jumps in with an answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zip the contents of the R package and ship it as my_package.zip to the cluster, i.e with the *spark-submit* command. This will place the zip file into the working directory of the SparkR script.

Then you can install the package within your R script:

```
 install.packages("my_package.zip",repos=NULL)
 library(my_package)
```

*DISCLAIMER: If your package depends on other packages, you will need to ship and install them manually.*

Comment: would you please take a look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36001256/should-i-pre-install-cran-r-packages-on-worker-nodes-when-using-sparkr