# should I pre-install cran r packages on worker nodes when using sparkr

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I want to use r packages on cran such as `forecast` etc with sparkr and meet following two problems.

1. Should I pre-install all those packages on worker nodes? But when I read the source code of spark [this file](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/RPackageUtils.scala), it seems that spark will automatically zip packages and distribute them to the workers via --jars or --packages. What should I do to make the dependencies available on workers?
2. Suppose I need to use functions provided by `forecast` in a `map` transformation, how should I import the package. Do I need to do something like following, import the package in the map function, will it make multiple import:

   `SparkR:::map(rdd, function(x){
     library(forecast)
     then do other staffs
   })`

Update:

After reading more source code, it seems that, I can use `includePackage` to include packages on worker nodes according to [this file](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/R/pkg/R/context.R). So now the problem becomes is it right that I have to pre-install the packages on nodes manually? And if that's true, what's the use case for --jars and --packages described in question 1? If that's wrong, how to use --jars and --packages to install the packages?

Comment: Why are you using  a non-exported function?

Comment: @piccolbo what does `non-exported function` mean? I try to run some function provided by cran packages parallel on workers. I think using sparkr can save me from managing a parallel computing system. But maybe it's wrong to use sparkr in this way. sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Non-exported means accessed using `:::` (triple colon) function or in other words functions which are not imported when you use `library(some_name)`.

Comment: @zero323 I am new to R and copy that `SparkR:::map` example from some other stackoverflow question, I meant to  express something like scala code `rdd.map{x => y}`. It's good to know about `:::` :)

Comment: BTW. If you need low level R access with Spark you may find https://github.com/onetapbeyond/opencpu-spark-executor interesting.

Comment: thanks @zero323 , a pity is that project relies on OpenCPU and I am limited in installing programs in platform. I'm now considering on whether to use javar to call r functions in scala code is a good  option.

Comment: It's a very unique situation where a whole API is removed by making it non-exported. Confusion is understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is boring to repeat this but **you shouldn't use internal RDD API** in the first place. It's been removed in the first official SparkR release and it is simply not suitable for general usage.

Until new low level API* is ready (see for example [SPARK-12922](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12922) [SPARK-12919](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12919), [SPARK-12792](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12792)) I wouldn't consider Spark as a platform for running plain R code. Even when it changes adding native (Java / Scala) code with R wrappers can be a better choice.

That being said lets start with your question:

1. `RPackageUtils` are designed to handle packages create with Spark Packages in mind. It doesn't handle standard R libraries.
2. Yes, you need packages to be installed on every node. From `includePackage` docstring:

   > The package is assumed to be installed on every node in the Spark cluster.

---

* If you use Spark 2.0+ you can use dapply, gapply and lapply functions.

Answer (score 0):

Add libraries works with spark 2.0+. For example, I am adding the package forecast in all node of cluster. The code works with Spark 2.0+ and databricks environment.

```
schema <- structType(structField("out", "string"))
out <- gapply(
  df,
  c("p", "q"),
  function(key, x) 
  if (!all(c("forecast") %in% (.packages()))){
     if (!require("forecast")) {
        install.packages("forecast", repos ="http://cran.us.r-project.org", INSTALL_opts = c('--no-lock'))
     }
  }  
  #use forecast
  #dataframe out
  data.frame(out = x$column, stringAsFactor = FALSE)
}, 
schema)
```

Answer (score -1):

a better choice is to pass your local R package by spark-submit archive option, which means you do not need install R package in each worker and do not install and compile R package while running `SparkR::dapply` for time consuming waiting. for example:

`Sys.setenv("SPARKR_SUBMIT_ARGS"="--master yarn-client --num-executors 40 --executor-cores 10 --executor-memory 8G --driver-memory 512M --jars /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/hadoop-lzo-0.4.15-cdh5.11.1.jar --files /etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml --archives /your_R_packages/3.5.zip --files xgboost.model sparkr-shell")`

when call `SparkR::dapply` function, let it call `.libPaths("./3.5.zip/3.5")` first. And you need notice that the server version R version must be equal your zip file R version.